# Xcode can't find my cell identifier

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

[image]I'm getting an error with my code that says...

> "Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell
>   with identifier ItemCell - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'?"

I've set the cell to `ItemCell` and I've run Product > Clean. It still can't find it. Can anyone see what I've done wrong? I've included a screen shot of my code and my storyboard.

```
import UIKit

 class ItemsViewController: UITableViewController {

  var itemStore: ItemStore!


@IBAction func addNewItem(_ sender: UIButton) {

    let newItem = itemStore.createItem()

    if let index = itemStore.allItems.index(of: newItem) {
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)

        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}

@IBAction func toggleEditingMode(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if isEditing {
        sender.setTitle("Edit", for: .normal)

        setEditing(false, animated: true)
    } else {
        sender.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)

        setEditing(true, animated: true)
    }
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height

    let insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(statusBarHeight, 0, 0, 0)
    tableView.contentInset = insets
    tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets

    tableView.rowHeight = 65
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return itemStore.allItems.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell", for: indexPath) as! ItemCell

    let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]


    cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
    cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber
    cell.valueLabel.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"

    return cell 
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle,
                        forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {
        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]

        let title = "Delete \(item.name)"
        let message = "You sure ya wanna delete this?"

        let ac = UIAlertController(title: title,
                                   message: message,
                                   preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        let cancelAction  = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        ac.addAction(cancelAction)

        let deleteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in


        self.itemStore.removeItem(item)

        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    })
        ac.addAction(deleteAction)
        present(ac, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,
                        moveRowAt sourceIndexPath: IndexPath,
                        to destinationIndexPath: IndexPath) {
    itemStore.moveItem(from: sourceIndexPath.row, to: destinationIndexPath.row)
}
```

This is my ItemCell

```
 import UIKit

 class ItemCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var serialNumberLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var valueLabel: UILabel!

   }
```

And my ItemStore

```
  import UIKit

  class ItemStore {

  var allItems = [Item] ()


@discardableResult func createItem() -> Item {
    let newItem = Item(random: true)

    allItems.append(newItem)

    return newItem
}


func removeItem(_ item: Item) {
    if let index = allItems.index(of: item) {
        allItems.remove(at: index)
    }
}

func moveItem(from fromIndex: Int, to toIndex: Int) {
    if fromIndex == toIndex {
        return
    }

    let movedItem = allItems[fromIndex]

    allItems.remove(at: fromIndex)

    allItems.insert(movedItem, at: toIndex)
}

 }
```

Comment: What is the class type in storyboard for the prototype cell?

Comment: 1. Where are you registering for the tableViewCell? 2. In your code search for `register`...do you find anything? share all instances.

Comment: Just try delete the UIView that is present above the TableViewCell under the table view hierarchy or have you set the class for the UITableViewController to your class in that scene?.

Comment: I added the code from the rest of my controllers. Thanks for help!

Comment: @Honey Prototype cells are registered implicitly by the storyboard.

Comment: @vadian I know. Wanted to make sure that she wasn't  doing an extra registering through code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check your custom class name in storyboard as  `ItemCell.swift`  as your class name.

[image: Your custom class for tableview cell]

[image: Set custom class for tableview]

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // create a new cell if needed or reuse an old one
        let cell:ItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ItemCell") as! ItemCell

        let item = itemStore.allItems[indexPath.row]


        cell.nameLabel.text = item.name
        cell.serialNumberLabel.text = item.serialNumber
        cell.valueLabel.text = "$\(item.valueInDollars)"

        return cell
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have set the correct custom class for the cell (`ItemCell` in this case) in Identity Inspector.